# JPA Date Comparsion in where clause

Tags: date, jpa, comparison

I'm New to JPA, how to convert the following snippet in JPA Criteria Builder?

select t from t1 t where( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - t.createTstamp )  <  200

Comment: and what does an internet search for Criteria and dates show?

Comment: I didnt found any helpful information in this. Do you any idea about this @NeilStockton?

Answer (score 0):

Achieved solution using CriteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery and Root classes.

```
Expression currentDate = em.getCriteriaBuilder().currentDate();
Expression createTmstp = sroot.get("createTmstp");

predicateList.add(cb.greaterThan( (cb.diff(currentDate, brokerAdvTmstp)),200));

Predicate[] predicates = predicateList.toArray(new Predicate[predicateList.size()]);

cq.where(predicates);

Query qry = em.createQuery(cq);
```